# How to read a Correlation matrix and form a Scatterplot matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, r-corrplot

I have a correlation matrix in excel follows:

```
dfA <- read.table(text=
      "beta1   beta2   beta3   beta4   beta5   beta6       X      X2      X3
beta1  1.0000 -0.2515 -0.2157  0.7209 -0.7205  0.4679  0.1025 -0.3606 -0.0356
beta2 -0.2515  1.0000  0.9831  0.1629 -0.1654 -0.5595 -0.0316  0.0946  0.0829
beta3 -0.2157  0.9831  1.0000  0.1529 -0.1559 -0.4976 -0.0266  0.0383  0.0738
beta4  0.7209  0.1629  0.1529  1.0000 -1.0000 -0.2753  0.0837 -0.1445  0.0080
beta5  0.4679 -0.5595 -0.4976 -0.2753  1.0000  0.2757  0.0354 -0.3149 -0.0596
beta6 -0.7205 -0.1654 -0.1559 -1.0000  0.2757  1.0000 -0.0837  0.1451 -0.0081
X      0.1025 -0.0316 -0.0266  0.0837 -0.0837  0.0354  1.0000  0.0278 -0.0875
X2    -0.3606  0.0946  0.0383 -0.1445  0.1451 -0.3149  0.0278  1.0000  0.2047
X3    -0.0356  0.0829  0.0738  0.0080 -0.0081 -0.0596 -0.0875  0.2047  1.0000", 
      header=TRUE)
```

I have just the correlation matrix and not the original data from which the matrix is formed, so, I tried to read the this matrix into matrix in R with this code:

```
 B <- as.matrix(dfA)
```

But when I try to form a scatter plot matrix with the following code:

```
library(corrplot)
corrplot(B, method="circle")
```

I receive error

```
Error in corrplot(B, method = "circle") : The matrix is not in [-1, 1]!
```

Kindly help me with this problem.

Comment: I may have misunderstood but I think you are creating a correlation matrix of a correlation matrix graph made from Excel which is not going to fly.  You can only use "tidy" data to perform correlation matrix.   Tidy in this case means you need unique observations as rows and beta1, beta2, beta3, ... are your columns.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @BGA actually I have a correlation matrix in excel, so, I'm trying to make a scatterplot matrix graph from that correlation matrix.

Comment: ah.  but same concept.  i believe you still need the raw data to perform your scatterplot matrix.  do you not have the raw data anymore?  if it is accessible it's pretty easy to bring it into r as a data frame from csv or excel.

Comment: @BGA I don't have the raw data. So, there's no hope to make the scatterplot?

Comment: you are merely creating circles from decimal numbers at this point and that is not scatter plotting anymore.

Comment: @BGA but the coefficients of correlation are decimal number. I'm getting something really wrong here.

Comment: I haven't used the `corrplot` package, but the error you are getting is that the values in your matrix are not in the interval [-1, 1]. it may be case that there is a numerical precision issue. Looking at the values of the matrix, the likely offenders are the 1s. They are probably actually 1.000000001 or something. Take a closer look at the values, you may need to perform a minor manipulation. Before this, as BGA says, you should double check what type of object `corrplot` is looking for. read `?corrplot` and make sure that its first argument is a correlation matrix.

Comment: Happy, your code should work - it is absolutely fine to pass matrix like this to `corrplot`. If I copy and paste your code it works, so it must be precision as Imo says. Try `corrplot(round(B, 4), method="circle")`

Comment: you're welcome Happy. Numerical precision (if this is what the problem is) has caught me out many times - it doesn't help that R will only print out a set number of digits to the screen, to lull you into a false security. You could try `print(B, digits=15)` to see? (ps. it was great that you added your data, but sometimes  finer details are needed - adding the results of `dput(dfA)` is a good method to add the data)

Comment: @user20650 yes it was one of the problems. I will surely keep in mind your suggestions for future. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## corrplot() Solution

Update to my first post using ggplot based on user20650's comments above. user20650 shows that the likely source of error was rounding mistakes leading to some numbers being out of the permissible [-1,1] range and that rounding solves this issue. I was able to produce a plot using corrplot() as well.

At this point, running corrplot() yields the following plot:

```
corMat<-as.matrix(dfA)

library('corrplot')
corrplot(corMat, method='circle')
```

[image]

## ggplot() Solution

You can also do this in ggplot2 with a few additional steps. I personally think it looks much better.

1) I get rid of the redundant information in the lower triangle of the matrix.

```
corMat[lower.tri(corMat)]<-NA

> print(corMat)
      beta1   beta2   beta3  beta4   beta5   beta6       X      X2      X3
beta1     1 -0.2515 -0.2157 0.7209  0.4679 -0.7205  0.1025 -0.3606 -0.0356
beta2    NA  1.0000  0.9831 0.1629 -0.5595 -0.1654 -0.0316  0.0946  0.0829
beta3    NA      NA  1.0000 0.1529 -0.4976 -0.1559 -0.0266  0.0383  0.0738
beta4    NA      NA      NA 1.0000 -0.2753 -1.0000  0.0837 -0.1445  0.0080
beta5    NA      NA      NA     NA  1.0000  0.2757 -0.0837  0.1451 -0.0081
beta6    NA      NA      NA     NA      NA  1.0000  0.0354 -0.3149 -0.0596
X        NA      NA      NA     NA      NA      NA  1.0000  0.0278 -0.0875
X2       NA      NA      NA     NA      NA      NA      NA  1.0000  0.2047
X3       NA      NA      NA     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA  1.0000
```

2) Then I use reshape2::melt() to transform the matrix into long form and create a formatted version of values that only show up to two decimal places. This will be useful for the plot.

```
library(reshape2)
m<-melt(corMat)
m<-data.frame(m[!is.na(m[,3]),]) # get rid of the NA matrix entries
m$value_lab<-sprintf('%.2f',m$value)
```

Here's what the data looks like:

```
> head(m)
    Var1  Var2   value value_lab
1  beta1 beta1  1.0000      1.00
10 beta1 beta2 -0.2515     -0.25
11 beta2 beta2  1.0000      1.00
19 beta1 beta3 -0.2157     -0.22
20 beta2 beta3  0.9831      0.98
21 beta3 beta3  1.0000      1.00
```

3) Finally, I feed this data into ggplot2 - primarily relying on geom_tile() to print the matrix and geom_text() to print the labels over each tile. You can dress this up more if you want.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(m, aes(Var2, Var1, fill = value, label=value_lab),color='blue') + 
  geom_tile() + 
  geom_text() +
  xlab('')+
  ylab('')+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: @user20650 Oh cool. I submitted my answer before I saw your comment on the question. I'll update my post to include corrplot(). Also, why do I need the byrow argument? It seems matrix() is already placing the values correctly into corMat.

Comment: Good eye. I'm going to update with OP's new read.table() import.

Comment: it works perfectly (I have made both the scatterplot matrices) thank you for your answer and such step by step code explanation. Actually ggplot looks much better then the circle based scatter plot.  I apologize the way I provided by data. Could you please help me how can I import correlation matrix into R in matrix format?